# PHP mail form POST returns true instead of value?

Tags: php, forms, post

I have form:

```
<form action="processForm.php" method="POST" class="contactForm">
  <select class="support-select" name="contactPerson" required="required">
    <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Select Your Contact</option>
    <option value="james">James Jones</option>
    <option value="marsha">Marsha May</option>
  </select>
```

And in processForm.php I have:

```
$contactPerson = isset($_POST['contactPerson']);

$success = mail( $recipient, EMAIL_SUBJECT, "NAME: $senderName\nEMAIL: $senderEmail\nCONTACT: $contactPerson\nMESSAGE: $message", $headers );
```

I'm pretty sure the $_POST is where I'm having trouble as it just returns a 1 or 0 if selected. I don't need to know true/false I need the value and/or the text. I will settle for value.

Comment: `isset` returns `TRUE` || `FALSE`

Comment: Yeah I meant that whole line when I said $_POST. What is that line supposed to be?

Comment: well typically I do a if it is isset I sterilize/validate the data otherwise I create error messages and won't send/do the mailing or whatever it is.

Comment: It shouldbe : $contactPerson = $_POST['contactPerson'];

Comment: @SankalpBhatt I'm not a big PHP guy but when I made this form several months ago I know I changed everything from just $_POST to isset($_POST... for some reason. I don't remember now but I know I made that change on purpose.

Comment: @Class It's for an internal network only and used only by employees so it isn't as big a deal, but I do wish I had the skills to sterilize the data. It's also not going into a db, just sending a single email. Not enough reasons not to sterilize, I know, but as you can tell by my question, those kinds of options will need to be another lesson.

Comment: @o_O: You may have changed your `if ($_POST['param'])`s to `if (isset($_POST['param']))`, which is correct. If the `param` was absent in the `POST` data you have a problem with the former case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`isset()` returns a boolean value `either true or false`

[source](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

so you are trying to assign a bolean value to `$contactPerson`.

instead you should use

```
$contactPerson = isset($_POST['contactPerson'])?$_POST['contactPerson']:FALSE;

if($contactPerson)
{
 //send mail
}
```

Answer (score 1):

change `$contactPerson = $_POST['contactPerson'];` , remove isset it will return a boolean only

Answer (score 1):

You can use a *ternary operator* here because when you use [`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) it will return boolean `true` or `false`

```
$contactPerson = (isset($_POST['contactPerson']) ? $_POST['contactPerson'] : '');
```

*Ternary operator* is nothing but a shorthand for `if` condition, so the above code means, if `$_POST['contactPerson']` is set, assign the value to `$contactPerson` else assign blank value.

Answer (score 1):

This is because of `$contactPerson = isset($_POST['contactPerson']);` `$contactPerson` will got only True or false not Email.

Try ternary operator:

```
$contactPerson = (isset($_POST['contactPerson']))? $_POST['contactPerson'] : 'default mail';
```

Comment: what is it `'$_POST['contactPerson']'` LOL - it's ERROR! (now well)

Answer (score 1):

`isset` is used to check whether a variable/array element is initialized. It will return either `true` or `false`.

```
// execute following code if $_POST contains a parameter
// for contactPerson. the isset check makes sure that
if (isset($_POST['contactPerson'])) {
    // here is the main difference from your code,
    // you had used an unnecessary isset
    $contactPerson = $_POST['contactPerson']; 

    $success = mail( $recipient, EMAIL_SUBJECT, "NAME: $senderName\nEMAIL: $senderEmail\nCONTACT: $contactPerson\nMESSAGE: $message", $headers );
}
```